# IOS notifications React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, notifications

I have followed the react native firebase documentation to display notification images on iOS.

But the pictures are only displayed when the app is in background, it doesn't work when the app is in foreground.

Link to the documentation : https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/ios-notification-images

What is the problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean that it "doesn't work" when the app is in foreground? You need to handle foreground notifications https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/notifications#handling-interaction

Comment: I have already integrated handle foreground notification, but the picture appears only when the app is not in foreground. It seems impossible to receive image notification when the app is open (foreground). Thank

Answer (score 0):

as of v6 rnfirestore library do not support foreground push notifications, so you need to integrate some library like https://github.com/react-native-push-notification-ios/push-notification-ios in order to get this function to work

Comment: I have already integrated handle foreground notification, but the picture appears only when the app is not in foreground. It seems impossible to receive image notification when the app is open (foreground). Thank